# ShadowMap doesn't render as expected with shader

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, shader, vertex-shader

Im currently trying to create a game where you visit planets in LibGDX for Java. To do this I use a `TiledMap` which is basically just an array of tiles to represent the planets themselves. To get the necessary curvature, I use a Shader; it works by assigning an angle to every vertex and placing it according to the camera position. It looks like this:

Fragment:

```
precision highp float;  

varying vec2 uv;
varying vec4 v_color;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, uv) * v_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Vertex:

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform float WORLD_WIDTH;
uniform float CAM_X;

varying vec2 uv;
varying vec4 v_color;

const float PI = 3.14159265;

void main() {
    uv = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;

    float radius = a_position.y;

    float angle = 2.0 * PI * ((a_position.x-CAM_X)/ WORLD_WIDTH);
    float camAngle = 2.0 * PI * (CAM_X / WORLD_WIDTH);

    vec3 newPos = vec3(a_position);
    newPos.x = CAM_X + cos(-angle + 0.5 * PI) * radius ;
    newPos.y = sin(-angle + 0.5 * PI) * radius;

    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * vec4(newPos, 1.0);
}
```

Applying this shader without anything else looks like this:

[image]

I now use a shadowmap to get lighting into the game. This is done by drawing shades of grey onto a texture and strechting the texture over the gameplay after that (specifically a `FrameBuffer`). Without any shaders it looks like this:

[image]

If I now apply the shader to not only the tiles, but the shadowmap as well, I get a distorted shadowmap:

[image]

I believe this is due to the shader using vertices to achieve curvature. The shadowmap only has four vertices, which cant really get stretched to achieve curvature, while every tile in the map has four vertices, which allow for a nice effect. I currently don't know, how the curvature effect could still be achieved, so please if you have an idea or some other advice let me know, you don't necessarily have to post any code, just a general method would be nice too.

EDIT: I now tried this using a fragment shader:

This is the fragment shader I tried to use to render the shadowmap, it resulted in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3xB.png). As you can see its got a basic circular form, but is kinda distorted (I know the problem arises out of how the angles are used, but Im not sure how to fix it yet). This is how the texture is represented in the shader (with uv): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I1rj.png

```
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform float TEXTURE_WIDTH;
uniform float TEXTURE_HEIGHT;
uniform float VIEWPORT_WIDTH;
uniform float VIEWPORT_HEIGHT;
uniform float CAM_X;
uniform float CAM_Y;

varying vec2 uv;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {

    // THE RATIO OF TEXTURE WIDTH TO TEXTURE_HEIGHT WHICH YOU MULTIPLY WITH UV.X TO NOT ALLOW STRETCHING
    // (LOOK AT HOW THE TEXTURE IS REPRESENTED TO UNDERSTAND)
    float k = TEXTURE_WIDTH / TEXTURE_HEIGHT;
    uv.x *= k;

    // THE CENTER OF THE PLANET RELATIVE TO TEXTURE_HEIGHT AS 1
    vec2 m;
    m.x = (k * VIEWPORT_WIDTH) / (2.0 * TEXTURE_WIDTH);
    m.y = - ((CAM_Y - 0.5 * VIEWPORT_HEIGHT) / TEXTURE_HEIGHT);

    // THE DISTANCE FROM CURRENT UV COORDINATE TO CENTER
    float d = distance(uv, m);

    // THE RANGE OF ANGLES
    float a = abs(atan(m.x/m.y)) * 2.0;

    // THE ANGLE OF THE CURRENT UV COORDINATE
    // + THE LEFTOFER ANGLE FROM HOW MUCH THE PLAYER HAS MOVED FROM THE CLOSEST INTEGER POSITION
    float angle = atan((uv.x - m.x)/(uv.y - m.y)) + (CAM_X - floor(CAM_X)) * (a / VIEWPORT_WIDTH);

    // ASIGN THE DISTANCE AND ANGLE TO ONE POINT IN THE TEXTURE
    uv.x = ((angle + 0.5 * a) / a)*(VIEWPORT_WIDTH / TEXTURE_WIDTH);
    uv.y = d + m.y;

    // GET THE COLOR OF THE TEXTURE AT THIS POINT
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, uv) * v_color;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you draw your shadows using the same curvature vertex shader as you used for your tile map? If the problem is that your method for drawing shadows doesn't have enough vertices, can you tesselate the shadows into multiple sprites? Or instead update your shader to calculate curved coordinates in the fragment shader instead of the vertex shader, and then use the same curvature fragment shader for drawing shadows.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hi, sorry for coming back to you with this just now, but I still have this problem and its extremely depressing not finding anything to solve it. Calculating the curved coordinates within a fragment shader is probably the way to go and I tried implemting it myself, but it doesnt quite work. Ill add my approach, but if you have any idea how you would do that, please post it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the same vertex and fragment shader as the rest of your graphics, except maybe for color calculations? I don't understand why it wouldn't line up exactly if you're drawing them both with the same camera.

Comment: @Tenfour04 When drawing the map, every tile gets drawn individiually, this means that every vertex can be positioned according to its position. When drawing the shadowmap, there are only four vertexes, with which you will not be able to achieve such curvature. Of course splitting the shadowmap up would be an option, but that would destroy the interpolation effect, so its not really a good option.